# Difference in Output between Pytorch and ONNX model

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, onnx, onnxruntime

I converted the transformer model in Pytorch to ONNX format and when i compared the output it is not correct.
I use the following script to check the output precision:
output_check = np.allclose(model_emb.data.cpu().numpy(),onnx_model_emb, rtol=1e-03, atol=1e-03) # Check model.

Here is the code i use for converting the Pytorch model to ONNX format and i am also pasting the outputs i get from both the models.

Code to export model to ONNX :

```
`model.eval()

torch.onnx.export(model,                     # model being run
(features.to(device), masks.to(device)),  # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                "../model/unsupervised_transformer_cp_55.onnx",  # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
                opset_version=13,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                input_names = input_names,   # the model's input names
                output_names = output_names # the model's output names
                )`
```

Inference using ONNXRuntime:

```
import onnxruntime as ort
import onnx
import numpy as np

# Load the ONNX model
onnx_model = onnx.load("../model/unsupervised_transformer_cp_55.onnx")
# Check that the model is well formed
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
# Load ONNX Inference Session.
ort_sess = ort.InferenceSession('../model/unsupervised_transformer_cp_55.onnx')

model_result = list()
onnx_model_result = list()
latency_result = list()
output_check_result = list()

def check_output(pageid_transform_list): 
    for test_data in pageid_transform_list:
        X_training, X_training_lengths = get_padded_data(test_data, max_seq_len)     # Get Padded Data.
        X_list,mask_list,X_lengths_list = get_masks(X_training,X_training_lengths)   # Get Masks.
        features = torch.stack([torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.int64) for x in X_list]) # Process Input.
        masks = torch.stack([torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.int8) for x in mask_list])
        model_emb = model(features.to(device), masks.to(device))                          # Get Embeddings.
        embs_reshape = model_emb.reshape(-1,1024,24)
        latency = []
        output = ort_sess.run(None, {'features': features.numpy(),'masks':  masks.numpy()})
        start = time.time()
        onnx_model_emb = output[0]
        latency.append(time.time() - start)
#         print("OnnxRuntime cpu Inference time = {} ms".format(format(sum(latency) * 1000 / len(latency), '.2f')))
        output_check = np.allclose(model_emb.data.cpu().numpy(),onnx_model_emb, rtol=1e-03, atol=1e-03) # Check model outputs
        model_result.append(model_emb.data.cpu().numpy()), onnx_model_result.append(onnx_model_emb), latency_result.append(latency),output_check_result.append(output_check)
    return model_result, onnx_model_result, latency_result,output_check_result
```

I expected the output to be same from both the models and need help in debugging as to what i am doing wrong here.

[Here you can see the output result from the Pytorch model and the ONNX model for some sample records. They do not match. Can anybody please help with the same?] https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgWcR.png

Comment: do you solve that? same happened to me